# Black screen after login

Tags: windows-7, graphics-card, login

I have next configuration:
HP ProBook 450 G1 laptop with ATI HD 8750M graphics card.

After installing windows 7, and all drivers available from HP support page, problem started. After I enter my user password, it takes roughly 7 minutes to show desktop and another minute or two for computer to become responsive. I can start Task Manager, and from there I see explorer.exe (because I googled some users don't have that process started).

I know this is similar to all those "black screen" problems but it is again different.

What can I do to resolve this issue?

Comment: There is not enough information here for us to know what the problem is or how to help you. Are you receiving any error messages? Are there anything in the Event Viewer to indicate a problem? Have you run any diagnostics on the hardware?

Comment: @charlierb Upon logging in, I entered task manager and manually restarted explorer.exe and that helped to show desktop but I couldn't click any item in Start Menu. I did sfc /scannow without any errors. Event Viewer shows some errors (WMI in application logs, 3 from Service Control Manager -> The Background Intelligent Transfer Service service hung on starting is one of those, and 2 from HP support assitant). I will try my best to give more info.

Comment: I would suggest thorough diagnostics on the hardware. Recently I had a client who had a very similar problem and it turned out to be a bad hard drive. Your laptop should have system diagnostics on-board. On restart, press `ESC` when it prompts “*Press the ESC key for Startup Menu*”. Then choose diagnostics.

Comment: @CharlieRB Yes, I did that, everything seems to be fine. No problems detected.

Comment: About the only thing left is to do a repair installation or complete reinstall of Windows. Maybe something went wrong during the last install that has caused this issue.

Comment: @CharlieRB The problem is this is second time that Windows is installed on this laptop in 7 months period. And both times the same thing, I hoped after second install problem will be gone ( I suspected at bad drivers installed the first time by my colleague). Maybe to try install windows 8.1 on it...